# SVG React Component will not center

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have an svg in my site that I wanted to animate, so I changed the tag from img to svg for the animation to work.

Unfortunately, this led me to the issue of properly centering my SVG in my window. I cannot do this responsively

I have created a sandbox to reproduce the issue for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-fast-xdjzk

What I have tried includes:

```
 .globe-svg {
   position: absolute
   transform: (-50%, -50%)

 .App {
    display: flex,
    align-items: center,
    justify-content: center
```

- manipulating the viewport sizes

The closest I have been able to get to what I want is using `position: relative` and setting `left` to a certain percentage but this is not responsive at all, so `left: 50%` would work in one viewport width only.

Comment: a) why have you given the svg a left of 41% b) your viewBox value is invalid it must be 4 numbers, percentages and auto are invalid.

Comment: I don't find the code you mention in the Codesandbox, but try `position: absolute transform: (-50%, -50%) left: 50% top: 50%` and make sure parent's `position` is not `static` ( `relative` )

Comment: @RobertLongson thats just what gave it the closest to middle for a view I was looking at as an example. I didn’t view it as a valid solution.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you calculate viewBox based off of the width of the container or is this not recommended?

Comment: sure if you want to.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I tried what you showed me but its still not centered. The CSS is at the very top in the styles.css file. SVG has a class name of .globe-svg

Comment: @RobertLongson so once I set the viewport, do I want my svg to be at a width of 50% for it to fit in the middle?

Comment: depends how big you want the SVG to appear. Do you want it to fill the viewport or only fill half of the viewport?

Comment: @RobertLongson I want it to be in the direct center of its parent div or component in this case with a height of 30% of the its parent's height

Comment: @RobertLongson I got it to work assigning values to the viewBox and then using Toni's suggestion with some modifications.

Do you want to post an answer so I can give you credit for this? It only worked because viewBox needed proper values

Comment: is `.App` the parent element to the `svg` ? I tried removing all the svg styles and it got centered

Comment: Yes this is visible in the index file. What do you mean by remove all of the svg styles? @ToniMichelCaubet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to Robert Longson and Toni Michel Caubet for helping me piece this together but I figured it'd be best to post the solution I came up with here since the discussion was mainly in the comment thread.

First I will address my errors:

1. Invalid ViewBox

As Robert pointed out, I misunderstood how to use viewBox and as a consequence used incorrect values. To help resolve my issue, I set my viewBox to `0 0 380 380` and adjusted height and width accordingly

```
    <svg
      width="380px"
      height="380px"
      viewbox="0 0 380 380"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      className={`globe-svg ${classActive}`}
    >
```

2. HTML, Body reset for App 100% height

This is necessary for the app to be at 100% height and have an effect on the rest of the element's CSS.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Main Changes to App and Svg CSS

To actually center the SVG after making these key changes, I used a combination of flexbox and `transform:translate()`. I tried this earlier before posting, but due to the not having made two changes I needed to do above at that time period, it could not work properly as a solution beforehand.

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.globe-svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Thank you again for your help!